# HTML5 <Dialog> Only works on chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, modal-dialog

Using a dialog on a website appears to only work on chrome, on other browsers and on an iphone the dialog is open permanently and all over the place. Is there something I should be using instead of `<dialog>`?

```
<p><button id="launchStyledModal">Learn More</button></p>

 <dialog id="styledModal">
    Insert dialog text here
    <button id="close">Close</button> 
 </dialog>
 <script src="js/dialog.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {

// Get the buttons.

var styledModalBtn = document.getElementById('launchStyledModal');
var close = document.getElementById('close');


// Get the dialogs.
var styledModal = document.getElementById('styledModal');

// Setup Event Listeners

styledModalBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) 
{

  e.preventDefault();

  styledModal.showModal();

});

close.addEventListener('click', function(e) 
{
    this.parentNode.close();
});


};
```

Comment: yes.. some well defined/stable/cross browser dialog from some framework like bootstrap, dojo, jquery plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 Dialog works in the following browsers:

- Chrome 37+
- Opera 29+
- Android Browser 40+
- Chrome for Android 42+

For more info visit http://caniuse.com/#search=dialog

There is a polyfill available on github: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill

Comment: Is there any alternatives I could that produce the same effect? It seems a bit useless if it only works on a selected few browsers considering everyone uses different browsers?

Comment: I update my answer. Pleas accept it as answer if it answers your question

Comment: Here is an alternative polyfill:
https://github.com/nuxodin/dialog-polyfill

Comment: Now firefox and safari also supports the dialog-element